# How to pass variables into a command in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and I am trying to pass my variables from my while read loop of a csv file into my command as seen below, but the variables don't seem to be being passed properly.

I know the command is correct as i tested it with hard coded values.

Can someone tell me how to pass f1 f3 etc into the { command } properly?

```
while read f1 f3 f5
do
        #filename = $bootydir+"/"+$f1
        #echo $filename
        { timeout 20 airodump-ng -a -w bob --bssid $f1 --channel $f3 --output-format cap --write-interval 1  wlan0mon; } &
        PID=$!
        echo "xterm"
        xterm -e "aireplay-ng --deauth 20 -a $f1 wlan0mon;"

        sleep 20
        #kill scan
        kill -TERM $PID

done < $bootydir/sorted.csv
```

Comment: Replace the braces `{....}` with `(...)` parenthesis to background the command within its own subshell. Backgrounding a braced group seems an odd way to go.

Comment: The variables should be correctly passed. Can you run your script with `bash -x yourfile` to get a debug log, as well as adding `declare -p f1 f3` as the first line in the loop to show their variables in an unambiguous way?

Comment: A possible cause may be the fields of `sorted.csv` are separated by commas. Try to modify your `read` line to `while IFS=, read -r f1 f3 f5`.

Comment: the xterm line gets f1 just fine so i know its not the var.

Comment: That uses it in a different context, so it could still be the var. For example, if the variable contains quotes like CSV fields sometimes do, it'll work in the xterm line but not the airodump line. The debug log would make this clear.

Comment: Substituting contents directly into `xterm -e "..."` is a good way to get shell injection vulnerabilities if the names in your first column are ever out of your control (indeed, next wifi network I create, I might call it `$(rm -rf ~)` just to make a [Bobby Tables-esque](https://xkcd.com/327/) point). In general, if you want to generate a shell command as a string, substituting variables into it safely requires some special techniques (f/e, `printf -v airplay_cmd '%q ' aireplay-ng --deauth 20 -a "$f1" wlan0mon; xterm -e "$airplay_cmd"` would be safe).

Answer (score 0):

1. `while read f1 f3 f5` won't read a CSV file. You'll need `while IFS=, read f1 f3 f5` or (much better) a programming language with an actual CSV parsing library.
2. To avoid anything in the `while` loop swallowing standard input you should use `while read -u 3 … done 3< …`.
3. You don't need the grouping - `{ timeout 20 …; } &` could be simply `timeout 20 … &`.
4. [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!
5. Why do you `timeout 20` *and* kill after 20 seconds? `timeout 20` already sends SIGTERM after 20 seconds.

Comment: actually it does read the CSV file just fine.  my problem was that it needed to read f1 f2 f3 f4

Answer (score 0):

problem was the f1 f3 f5 were not valid.. I only have 4 columns f1 f2 f3 f4
so f5 was messing up all the orders and giving me the wrong values. I saw this when I called declare and noticed the wrong values.